# Hyperledger explorer throwing error when trying to connect to peer at 443 port

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-explorer

I am trying to run Hyperledger Explorer on a network running on the IBM Blockchain Platform. The peer is running on port 7051. The application is throwing an error when I use specify port 7051 in my connection profile.

```
[2020-11-20T14:57:26.551] [ERROR] FabricClient - Error: Missing port parameter
explorer.mynetwork.com      |     at module.exports.checkParameter (/opt/explorer/node_modules/fabric-common/lib/Utils.js:631:8)
explorer.mynetwork.com      |     at DiscoveryService._buildUrl (/opt/explorer/node_modules/fabric-common/lib/DiscoveryService.js:663:58)
explorer.mynetwork.com      |     at DiscoveryService._buildPeer (/opt/explorer/node_modules/fabric-common/lib/DiscoveryService.js:633:20)
explorer.mynetwork.com      |     at DiscoveryService._processPeers (/opt/explorer/node_modules/fabric-common/lib/DiscoveryService.js:553:15)
explorer.mynetwork.com      |     at DiscoveryService._processMembership (/opt/explorer/node_modules/fabric-common/lib/DiscoveryService.js:505:42)
explorer.mynetwork.com      |     at DiscoveryService.send (/opt/explorer/node_modules/fabric-common/lib/DiscoveryService.js:334:55)
explorer.mynetwork.com      |     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

I have specified the port number along with the peer url already

```
"peers": {
    "xx-xx-xx-peer-x": {
        "url": "grpcs://xx-xx-xx-peer-x:443",
        "tlsCACerts": {
            "path": "/opt/explorer/app/platform/fabric/certs/peer1.crt"
        },
        "grpcOptions": {
            "ssl-target-name-override": "xx-xx-xx-peer-x"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this error as well, and I understand how frustrating it can be with such minimal documentation on these more obscure points. Granted, I am building my network from the binaries, and not the IBM Platform like you, but I feel that this is so similar to my issue that it's worth a shot for you to try this solution: I was able to solve it by making sure all of my Anchor Peers, in their respective `core.yaml` files, had their `peer.gossip.externalEndpoint`value filled out with not just the address but the port, too. This would be in the standard form of `<Address>:<Port>`.